# Response.write in application_error not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, error-handling, global-asax

Ok, I have a weird problem and can't find anything about it online. I'm trying to get custom application-level error handling working in ASP.NET. I have customErrors turned off in the web.config with the hopes of handling everything in application_error. Bear with me...

My code in `global.asax` is very simple:

```
void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("ERROR MESSAGE");
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    var error = Server.GetLastError();

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("ERROR MESSAGE");
    HttpContext.Current.ClearError();
}
```

I created a simple aspx page and threw an error in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`, and everything worked as expected, i.e.: I see "ERROR MESSAGE" on a blank page when an error occurs.

Now I dynamically add some user controls to that aspx page and everything renders as expected. If I then throw an error from INSIDE one of the controls, I only get a blank white page. "ERROR MESSAGE" does not appear.

Now I know that application_error is still firing because when I remove the call to ClearError(), I get a Yellow Screen Of Death. Also, I can execute a `Server.Transfer` in there and that works fine. But nothing will come out for `Response.Write`. 
This goes further: I can set `Response.StatusCode`, but a `Response.Redirect` will error out (and thus throw me into an infinite loop). Trying to write to the Event Log also errors out, but instead of throwing a new error, it throws the original, i.e.: "Input string was not in a correct format." when I try to convert a string to a number. As mentioned, `Response.Write` doesn't do anything, though it does not throw an error.

So looking at my trace log, in the second case (exception inside dynamically added user control) I see a full control tree and the error occurs right after `Begin Render`. In the first case, the tree is empty and the error is thrown either after Init or Load. Both times, trace.axd reports `Unhandled Execution Error`.

When I move the throw inside the control to the control's constructor or `OnInit`, things work as expected. When I move it to `OnLoad` or `Render`, it gets goofy.

So I'm wondering if at some point the Response object loses certain functionality. I've tried all sorts of permutations, from syntax (using HttpContext.Current.Response vs Context.Response vs pulling the Response object from the "sender" parameter), to moving the `ClearError()` or `Response.Clear()`, etc methods around, etc. I've tested the Response object for "null-ness" as well, and it never reports a null. I can set some response properties (http status code) but not others.

I'm using IIS7.5 integrated mode (.NET v4), but experienced similar problems when I tried Classic mode.

So I'm trying to solve this mystery, obviously, but my goal is to ultimately handle all errors, no matter what point in the asp.net lifecycle they occur, and to be able to write out some information from the handler (ie application_error).

Comment: Turn custom errors on and set a default error page.  That page will handle everything for you, and you should get all functionality back.  Don't expect to have session/request/response contexts available at the application level.

Comment: One of my requirements is to keep the original URL that threw the error in the browser, so I could do what you say by setting the redirectMode in web.config to ResponseRewrite, or doing a Server.Transfer in Application_Error. I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to this (I wanted more control within Application_Error itself), however, but it is a possible option. That said, why does the same code (Response.Writes) work in the transferred aspx, but not in Application_Error? I should be able to reverse engineer the transfer method to make mine work...

Answer (score 1):

Handled unhandled exceptions using this approach. Custom error is off in web.config.

All 3 options work.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

  Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
  this.Server.ClearError();
  
  this.Server.GetLastError();
 //DO SOMETHING WITH GetLastError() may be redirect to different pages based on type of error

  //Option 1:
  Response.Write("Error");
    
  //Option 2:
  Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");

  //Option 3:
  this.Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that kind of misses the point. The above methods all work when the error is thrown from a simple aspx page. But only the Server.Transfer method works when the error is thrown from a dynamically created custom control. Thanks, but this doesn't help.